# Dataflow BigQuery to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to create a dataflow script that goes from BigQuery back to BigQuery. Our main table is massive and breaks the extraction capabilities. I'd like to create a simple table (as a result of a query) containing all the relevant information.

The SQL query `'Select * from table.orders where paid = false limit 10'` is a simple one to make sure it works. The true query is more complex but connects to multiple tables within the same project.

This seems to work but I'd like to know what I can do to test it out?
Also, How can I get this to run automatically every morning?

```py
import logging
import argparse
import apache_beam as beam

PROJECT='experimental'
BUCKET='temp1/python2'


def run():
    argv = [
        '--project={0}'.format(PROJECT),
        '--job_name=test1',
        '--save_main_session',
        '--staging_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
        '--temp_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
        '--runner=DataflowRunner'
    ]

    with beam.Pipeline(argv=argv) as p:

        # Read the table rows into a PCollection.
        rows = p | 'read' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(
                query =  'Select * from `table.orders` where paid = false limit 10', 
                use_standard_sql=True))

        # Write the output using a "Write" transform that has side effects.
        rows  | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table='orders_test',
                dataset='external',
                project='experimental',
                schema='field1:type1,field2:type2,field3:type3',
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

Answer (score 0):

To run the job every day, you can use Airflow (GCP Composer) to schedule your execution. You can follow the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/run-apache-airflow-dag#create_a_dag)

You can complete this task using Airflow operators only, and no need to use Apache Beam or Dataflow.
I will recommend you have a look at BigQuery Operators for Airflow [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/writing-dags#gcp_operators) and [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery/index.html)

A full tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/bigquery/how-to-aggregate-data-for-bigquery-using-apache-airflow) includes the check operator.

If you must use Apache Beam, `which I don't recommend if you are not doing any transformation and integration of other data sources.`, then build a dataflow template using your apache beam script to execute your job. You can follow the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates). and you can execute it using Airflow or API calls.

You can easily read the data from BigQuery whatever our query is:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    # Read from BigQuery
    load_data_from_bq = (
        pipeline
        | "ReadBigQuery"
        >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
            query=query_string,
            project=PROJECT,
            use_standard_sql=True,
            gcs_location=bqtfs_options.gcs_location.get(),
            # method="DIRECT_READ"
        )
        # | "printer" >> beam.Map(lambda x: print(type(x)))
        
    )
    # Writ to BigQuery
    data_written = (
        load_data_from_bq
        | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table='orders_test',
            dataset='external',
            project='experimental',
            schema='field1:type1,field2:type2,field3:type3',
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
        )
    )
```

Last point:
Generally speaking, do not use `SELECT * FROM table` in BigQuery... it is expensive and not the best practice. check [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#avoid_select_)