# BigQuery to BigQuery DataFlow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I've had a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265480/dataflow-bigquery-to-bigquery) but it's three years old and I think GCP has changed since then.

What I'm trying to do is set up a data pipeline using DataFlow jobs to copy/transform data from one GBQ project into another GBQ project.

To create a DataFlow job, you need to choose a template and there is no template that matches my needs i.e. no BQ to BQ template.

There is an option to use a custom template (which I imagine would be a python script or something along those lines), but it seems odd that there is no BQ to BQ template. Is DataFlow not the right tool for this job? Should I just use scheduled queries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of transforms are these? Can they not be done using queries, BQ has lot of predefined functions and creating user defined functions

Comment: @vinayhudli nothing too crazy. basically pivoting a table and doing some aggregation. I think scheduled queries might be the right approach. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't necessarily need to use a template to use a Dataflow. You can write a new Beam pipeline and execute that using Dataflow as well. Based on your description sounds like this will be a pretty straightforward pipeline similar to this example - https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/cookbook/BigQueryTornadoes.java

Answer (score 0):

There is a way which is not very straight forward if you really want to use Dataflow template, you can use BigQuery to cloud storage template to store data in GCS and then cloud storage to BigQuery template to bring the data to destination project. However make sure you gave proper permission that is required to access the cloud storage buckets from the destination project.

Comment: Thanks @Chandra. That does sound more complicated than I need. I guess DataFlow is not the right tool for the job here. I think scheduled queries are

Answer (score 0):

If the transformations you want are not possible using SQL or not practical to use SQL, you can use Cloud Data fusion -> Integration studio. Here you can choose both source and sink as BigQuery and there are a number of options available for transformation component. It is similar to ETL tool. [Data Fusion Quickstart documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/quickstart).

Otherwise, you can simply execute or schedule a query as per your requirement in BigQuery itself and save the result of the query in another table [Saving query results in destination table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#:%7E:text=Enter%20a%20valid%20SQL%20query,and%20choose%20a%20Table%20name.).

Comment: Thanks. I decided to go with scheduled queries, but I'll definitely read up on Data Fusion